# How to copy Graphics Image of one Swing Component to another in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I just started my `Java` programming 3 months before and here with my issue that is-

How to copy a `JLabel` or `JPanel` Graphics to another `JLabel` or `JPanel`.

I have used -

```
<!--Source JLabel srcLabel-->
JLabel dest = new JLabel();
dest.paint(srcLabel.getGraphics());
panel.add(dest);
dest.validate();
```

but due to lack of knowledge I stucked here. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
 and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more information about how painting works.

Never use `getGraphics`, this is just a bad idea and will cause you no end of issues.

Generally speaking, you should avoid calling `paint` directly, and instead use `print` or `printAll`.  This will disable the double buffering inherent in the normal painting process which can issues

```
JLabel srcLabel = new JLabel();
JLabel dest = new JLabel();
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(srcLabel.getWidth(), srcLabel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
srcLabel.printAll(g2d);
g2d.dispose();
dest.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

This assumes that `srcLabel` has already been displayed and laid out.

Now the question is why?  Wouldn't be easier to simply set the `text` and `icon` properties of the second label so it matches the first?

Comment: Sir, my srcLabel is round and it contains a word, I tried your suggested code and it won't work, the dest JLabel is still showing plain.

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem and provide some more idea of what you are trying to achieve and why you're current approach isn't working. The basic idea of using `printAll` is the general approach of painting a component to an image. As I said, it might be simpler to just copy the properties